# VBA function to search for item contained in a Dictionary

Tags: excel, vba, function, dictionary, custom-functions-excel

I declare a Dictionary in VBA and fill it in with keys and values:

```vb
Sub UseDictionary()
Dim Z As New Dictionary

Z.Add key:="Norway", Item:="AAA"
Z.Add key:="Germany", Item:="AA"
Z.Add key:="USA", Item:="A"
Z.Add key:="France", Item:="AC"
Z.Add key:="Spain", Item:="B"
Z.Add key:="Greece", Item:="BC"

Dim numItems As Integer
numItems = Z.Count

MsgBox "The collection has " & numItems & " items."
End Sub
```

When I try to create a Function that sends back a value for a given key (a rating for a given country), it displays a #Value! error on my Excel sheet:

```vb
Function GetValueFromDict(Z As Object, key As String) As Variant
Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
Set dict = Z
If dict.Exists(key) Then
    GetValueFromDict = dict.Item(key)
Else
    GetValueFromDict = Null
End If
 
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use a Dictionary UDF

**In Excel**

- Use e.g. the formula

  ```
  =GetCountryRating("Germany")
  ```
- If you want the function to return an empty string when the country is not found, declare its result `As String` (instead of `As Variant`) and remove the *Else* clause.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private CountryDict As Scripting.Dictionary

Sub PopulateCountryDict()
    
    Dim Z As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Z.CompareMode = TextCompare
    
    Z.Add Key:="Norway", Item:="AAA"
    Z.Add Key:="Germany", Item:="AA"
    Z.Add Key:="USA", Item:="A"
    Z.Add Key:="France", Item:="AC"
    Z.Add Key:="Spain", Item:="B"
    Z.Add Key:="Greece", Item:="BC"
    
    Set CountryDict = Z
    
End Sub

Function GetCountryRating(ByVal Country As String) As Variant
    If CountryDict Is Nothing Then PopulateCountryDict
    If CountryDict.Exists(Country) Then
        GetCountryRating = CountryDict(Country)
    Else
        GetCountryRating = Null
    End If
End Function
```

**In VBA**

```vb
Sub UseDictionary()
    
    Dim Z As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Z.CompareMode = TextCompare
    
    Z.Add Key:="Norway", Item:="AAA"
    Z.Add Key:="Germany", Item:="AA"
    Z.Add Key:="USA", Item:="A"
    Z.Add Key:="France", Item:="AC"
    Z.Add Key:="Spain", Item:="B"
    Z.Add Key:="Greece", Item:="BC"
    
    Dim numItems As Long: numItems = Z.Count
    
    MsgBox "The dictionary has " & numItems & " items.", vbInformation
 
    Dim Country As String: Country = "Germany"
    Dim Rating As Variant: Rating = GetCountryRating(Z, Country)
    
    If IsNull(Rating) Then
        MsgBox "No rating found for " & Country & ".", vbExclamation
    Else
        MsgBox "The rating for " & Country & " is """ & Rating & """.", _
            vbInformation
    End If

End Sub

Function GetCountryRating( _
    ByVal dict As Scripting.Dictionary, _
    ByVal Country As String) _
As Variant
    If dict.Exists(Country) Then
        GetCountryRating = dict(Country) ' short for 'dict.Item(Country)'
    Else
        GetCountryRating = Null
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Glad you like it. I totally forgot about case sensitivity. I added the line `Z.CompareMode = TextCompare` so it will work even if you use `uSa`.